# How to access Raspberry Pi from the Internet with this network settings?

Tags: raspberry-pi

[image: Network topology with Raspberry]

From this diagram, how can I access my Raspberry Pi outdoor?

Comment: port-forwarding on the router.

Comment: Please note that the router's WAN IP address is private and dynamic. For a more bigger diagram, please refer to: https://s24.postimg.org/xea1m8wt1/Raspberry_Pi_access.png

Comment: use dynamic dns -> https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-port-forwarding/

Answer (score 1):

**One possible method**

Try to access your pi via dyndns. 
Should be working fine. 
--> Port forwarding

This is not the only way but it's one that is very common.